# Missing "Web Projects" in Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions in VS 2010 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I was trying to use IIS Express in developing my first ASP.NET MVC.
I searched on the web and found out that I need to check a box in
**Tools > Options > Projects And Solutions > Web Projects**

The only items under the Projects and Solution node are
General, Build and Run and VB Defaults

Sorry, just a newbie in the field of web development

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify, I opened up my version of 2010 Ultimate and everything was there.  I would suggest verifying that you have the latest version of MVC installed and IISExpress.  This is all that I could think of that would cause it to be missing from the options menu(s).